# Should I train my pokemon based on its normal or mega evolution stats?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Such as Sableye, he gains stat changes during his mega evolution. Before he mega evolves his best stats are his attack and defense, but when he mega evolves his best stats are his defense and special defense. So should I super train his mega stats or normal stats?

Comment: Depends on your play style. This question is a bit too broad as it stands.

Comment: @Texenox - not really, it depends on whether you are going to mega evolve the Pokemon or not. Seems to be a general strategy question to me, which we've [just reinforced](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/why-is-my-question-are-terrans-objectively-better-than-protoss-at-aggression-ha) as being topic and objectively answerable :-)

Comment: @Jake - for further reading, I'd suggest [Are there any cons to mega evolving?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/153630/28182)

Comment: @Robotnik At this point, I figured that much. Probably just the way it was worded made me think it was too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, it depends on how you intend to use the Pokemon. When you "Train Stats" you are gaining [Effort Value](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values) points. For every 4 EV points, a stat is raised by 1, with a maximum of 252EVs in a single stat (+63), and a maximum 510EVs (+127) across all stats.

So if we take a lvl 100 Sableye: regardless of whether it is mega evolved or not, putting 252 EVs into defense will increase defense by 63. The only thing that changes is its base stats (from 75 to 125)

Whether you decide to train based on a Pokemon's mega-evolution stats or not is going to depend greatly on the Pokemon and how you intend to use it. Some mega-evolutions are not advantageous in all situations and may necessitate not using them immediately due to changes to type, ability, or stats.

[Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/dex/xy/pokemon/) has a great collection of build strategies that are used in competitive play - you don't necessarily have to follow them to the letter, you can alter them to suit your play-style if you want. For what it's worth, their [guides on Sableye](http://www.smogon.com/dex/xy/pokemon/sableye/ou/) tend to recommend putting most of your EVs into bolstering the somewhat lackluster HP, and then dividing the rest between Defense and Special Defense. Doing damage by inflicting status conditions and using things like [Foul Play](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Foul_Play_%28move%29) to deal damage based on the *target*'s Attack stat.

Comment: I was going to use this pokemon to challenge the elite four member Phoebe. So my question should i increase the stats it gets when it mega evolves or work on its normal stats

Comment: Just train his stats; Mega evolution doesn't really enter into it. If you want him to hit harder, train Attack. If you want him to survive longer, train HP and Defense/SpecialDefense. Whatever you train will still be trained when he mega evolves. +63 to Defense is still +63 to Defense regardless of his stat changes from mega-evolving.

Comment: I know that its just since his mega boost his defense's should i increase those and mega him or dont mega him and just stick to his normal stats

Comment: And this goes for all my pokemon also my starter

Comment: THAT decision is up to you, and would be too opinion based for this site. Which pokemon you use in your team is up to you, as is which ones will/won't be mega evolving, and against NPC trainers it doesn't really matter, as you can just grind levels and over-power them. But Mega evolved or not, Sableye's strength is in his ability to use status moves, and mega-evolve to bounce oponents' status moves back. He is not much of an attacker, so it is best to train his HP and Def/SpD to improve his survivability.

Comment: @Jake - what is your Sableye's ability? if you caught it in game, it's unlikely to be 'Prankster' (which is it's hidden ability and preferred over Keen Eye or Stall). Against NPCs such at the elite four it won't matter too much, you're probably better off using its non-mega form and allowing another Pokemon to mega evolve.